# Why do I get a `java.nio.file.ProviderMismatchException` when I access `isEmpty()` on a staged file

Tags: nextflow

I am getting a `java.nio.file.ProviderMismatchException` when I run the following script:

```
process a {
    output:
        file _biosample_id optional true into biosample_id

    script:
    """
    touch _biosample_id
    """
}

process b {
    input:
        file _biosample_id from biosample_id.ifEmpty{file("_biosample_id")}

    script:
    def biosample_id_option = _biosample_id.isEmpty() ? '' : "--biosample_id \$(cat _biosample_id)"
    """
    echo \$(cat ${_biosample_id})
    """
}
```

i'm using a slightly modified version of [Optional Input](https://nextflow-io.github.io/patterns/index.html#_optional_input) pattern.

Any ideas on why I'm getting the `java.nio.file.ProviderMismatchException`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your [script](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/process.html#script) block, `_biosample_id` is actually an instance of the [nextflow.processor.TaskPath](https://github.com/nextflow-io/nextflow/blob/v21.10.6/modules/nextflow/src/main/groovy/nextflow/processor/TaskPath.groovy) class. So to check if the file (or directory) is empty you can just call it's `.empty()` method. For example:

```
script:
def biosample_id_option = _biosample_id.empty() ? '' : "--biosample_id \$(< _biosample_id)"
```

I like your solution - I think it's neat. And I think it should be robust (but I haven't tested it). The optional input pattern that is recommended will fail when attempting to stage missing input files to a remote filesystem/object store. There is a [solution](https://github.com/nextflow-io/nextflow/issues/1233) however, which is to keep an empty file in your `$baseDir` and point to it in your scripts. For example:

```
params.inputs = 'prots/*{1,2,3}.fa'
params.filter = "${baseDir}/assets/null/NO_FILE"

prots_ch = Channel.fromPath(params.inputs)
opt_file = file(params.filter)

process foo {
  input:
  file seq from prots_ch
  file opt from opt_file

  script:
  def filter = opt.name != 'NO_FILE' ? "--filter $opt" : ''
  """
  your_commad --input $seq $filter
  """
}
```